# User Defaults Couldn't write values for keys ( "Dictation SLS Languages Enabled" )

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, uitextfield

In my project I have a `UITextfield` with `.textContentType = .newPassword` . However if I run the app on my iPhone (XR, iOS 13.3) and tap on the `textField` I get this message:

> [User Defaults] Couldn't write values for keys (
>       "Dictation SLS Languages Enabled" ) in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x281d5e600> (Domain: com.apple.assistant.support,
>   User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null),
>   Contents Need Refresh: No): setting preferences outside an
>   application's container requires user-preference-write or
>   file-write-data sandbox access

I also get this message right before the other one:

> [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.ckbusiness.Wishlist due to error: Cannot save passwords for this app. Make sure you have set up Associated Domains for your app and AutoFill Passwords is enabled in Settings

But that message is because I have no associated domain set up for my app yet.

But why does the first error occurr? What does it mean and how can I fit it ?

By the way, that doesn't crash the app. Everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

for the User Defaults problem, i removed app with its' data, then quit simulator, then ran the app again and it worked..it seems a random glitch, I know this is not a solution but you could try.